# Android: LinearLayout with textview weights, unexpected behavior

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout, with different weights for two text views. If the order_title text view text is long, it distorts the order_by text view (it ends up in two lines). It seems as if order_title is no longer confined only to 60% width.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="whatever"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:layout_weight="0.6"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_by"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:layout_weight="0.4"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

(If it matters this entire layout is used inside a ListView as individual rows )

Pls note: if i surround each TextView inside its own LinearLayout, and then assign weights to them, instead of text views - the behavior is correct.

Comment: So `order_title` always has one line? I would try setting `android:singleLine="false"`

Comment: @Jasper , not getting your problem. exetly for what you are looking for?

it you want layout as you mentioned in your note, simply change
android:gravity="left" of your 'order_by'.

Comment: Please share some screenshots of the issue.